# Пространственные отношения в условиях отсутствия пространства

Tags: синтаксис

Вопрос чисто академического характера: могут ли быть определены как пространственные синтаксические отношения между словоформами, составляющими словосочетание, одна из которых обозначает состояние по значению глагола "находиться" и его синонимов, а другая - положение в предложении?

Спасибо.

Comment: Глубоко копаете! Тут бы с фонемами разобраться...

Comment: Вы тоже страдаете оттого, что Вам никто не отвечает? Ох, коллега, как я Вас понимаю...

Comment: ну, почему же именно "пространственные"? их, скорее, можно определить как "временнЫе": сказуемое возникает в речи раньше или позже подлежащего.

Comment: > ну, почему же именно "пространственные"? их, скорее, можно определить как "временнЫе"

Я понятия не имею, как их определить, - упомянув пространственные отношения, я только сделала предположение.

Comment: stopkran, мне очень нравится ваш юмор. Надеюсь на ваш комментарий к вопросу о том, чем связи отличаются от отношений (синтаксических, конечно).

Comment: София, я не понимаю сути даже начального вопроса (уловил лишь некоторую формальную двусмысленность). В вашем же ответе слишком много букв. О чём вообще здесь спор (в двух словах)?

Comment: http://russ.hashcode.ru/users/533/stopkran, (Ха-ха-ха) переформулированный вопрос звучит так: "В каких синтаксических отношения находятся компоненты словосочетания "находиться после сказуемого"?"

Comment: Господи, что я говорю?.. Stopkran, забудьте то, что я сейчас сказала, ибо суть разговора в следующем: "Петька! Приборы!" - "Есть приборы!" - "Петька! 15!" - "Есть 15!" - "А что приборы?" - "А что 15?"

Comment: stopkran,суть вопроса пока в том, что у нас есть две школы: академическая и общеобразовательная, и они существуют, не замечая друг друга - как говорится,  у каждого своя свадьба. Например,  академики под микроскопом изучают падежи, но не выделяют в предложении определения, обстоятельства и дополнения. Школьная наука, напротив, о значении падежей даже не догадывается, но второстепенные члены выделяет исправно. И если у вас появится желание поговорить с другом на отвлеченные темы, например  о пространственной семантике, то разговор из-за смешанной терминологии может просто не состояться.

Comment: @Noir, @София, ну ведь где-то же (в школьном или вузовском учебнике) это должно быть написано - в каких отношениях. Или в одном месте написано, что в хороших, а в другом - в плохих? Тогда приведите обе цитаты и своё мнение, а мы заценим.

--------------

Хотя, если вчитаться, вроде понятно. Действительно получилось что-то вроде "Петька, приборы" (только в оригинале там "300" было). И знаете, в чём недочёт? Глаз скользит по вашим определениям без задержки, и мозг за глазом тоже. Для задержки бывает ОЧЕНЬ полезно ставить ССЫЛКИ на оригиналы определений! (пруфы, пруфлинки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что в вашем вопросе есть неточность в терминологии, поэтому он так трудно понимается. Существует термин "синтаксическая связь", но нет "синтаксических отношений".Лучше сказать так: синтаксическая связь выражает различные отношения.

ОБЩАЯ ТЕРМИНОЛОГИЯ (из Грамматики-80)

1. Синтаксическая связь глагола и существительного определяется как управление. УПРАВЛЕНИЕ — это вид ПОДЧИНИТЕЛЬНОЙ СИНТАКСИЧЕСКОЙ СВЯЗИ слов в словосочетании, при котором главное слово (глагол, существительное, прилагательное) требует от зависимого  слова (существительного, местоимения) определённой падежной формы.
2. Посредством падежного УПРАВЛЕНИЯ выражаются различные виды ПРЕДМЕТНЫХ ИЛИ ПРЕДМЕТНО-ОПРЕДЕЛИТЕЛЬНЫХ (пространственных, временных и др.) ОТНОШЕНИЙ.
3. Пространственно-предметные отношения могут выражать различные падежи - в частности, П.п., Р.п., Т.п., например:

А) Находиться перед сказуемым, находиться после определяемого слова: Т.п. с предлогом и Р.п. с предлогом имеют пространственно-предметное значение, так как  место действия задается положением относительно предмета.

Б) Находиться в конце (начале, середине) предложения – П.п. (его местная разновидность) имеет собственно пространственное  значение (это его основное значение).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 1. Синтаксические связи и синтаксические отношения

Интернет подтвердил существование  «синтаксических отношений», поэтому я стала размышлять над содержанием термина, надеясь, что словосочетание, входя в предложение, приобретает качественно новое значение. Например: статья из газеты→ я прочитал статью из газеты. Но, кажется, ничего не изменилось. Были предметно-определительные отношения в словосочетании, и они перешли в предложение в том же виде (слово «газета» по-прежнему определяет слово «статья»). Далее у меня появилась возможность взять «Грамматику-80», и я убедилась, что академики отказались от обычного разбора, при котором выделяется определение, обстоятельство, дополнение (или объект), видимо сочтя их не очень строгими.
Поэтому существуют две системы описания одного явления. Мне больше нравится академическое, и я попробую обосновать своё мнение.

1. Желательно  четко разделять форму (грамматику)  и содержание (семантику).
2. Синтаксис (греч. syntaxis - построение, порядок) –  это чисто грамматическая категория.  Синтаксис словосочетания – это определения вида СИНТАКСИЧЕСКОЙ СВЯЗИ в словосочетании, синтаксис предложения – это структурная схема предложения.
3. Термин «отношения»  ( не синтаксические) уместен для описания  словосочетаний – это, точно, отношения между предметами, признаками и действиями. К этим отношениям привязана падежная система, которая является своеобразным мостиком от грамматики  к содержанию, так как семантика падежей очень подробно расписана.
4. Термин «синтаксические отношения  в предложении» мне кажется нестрогим – это, скорее, «СЕМАНТИЧЕСКИЕ ОТНОШЕНИЯ», которые формируются еще на уровне словосочетаний и переносятся в предложение. Тем не менее они используются в школьной практике, так как значения падежей там вообще не изучается.
5. В академической грамматике простое предложение строится по абстрактному образцу: субъект, его предикативный признак и объект, на который это предикативный признак направлен.Грамматика-80 систематизирует предложения по структуре, а определения, обстоятельства, дополнения называет наполнителями  или распространителями.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 2.  (к  ответу на вопрос)

Итак, мы рассматриваем словосочетание и ищем в нем «пространственные синтаксические отношения». С учетом вышесказанного, мне хотелось бы убрать слово «синтаксические». Тогда  пространственные отношения – это семантические отношения между  действием и предметом, когда с помощью предмета  задается пространство действия.  При этом предложение мы можем рассматривать как абстрактное пространство, заданное последовательностью слов.

Comment: Значит, все-таки пространственные отношения?..

Comment: Ну да, всё правильно. В словосочетании "находиться в конце предложения" конец предложения - это линейное пространство, и отношения между глаголом и существительным - пространственные. В этом случае существительное определяет МЕСТО действия, выраженного глаголом.

Comment: Спасибо, что развеяли сомнения :).

Comment: Любопытно, что они напишут про "пространственно-временные отношения в условиях отсутствия пространства-времени".

Comment: Подождем, пока Вы откроете  эту тему. Думаю, что количество просмотров Вас не разочарует.

Answer (score 0):

Вы имеете в виду высказывания типа "в английском языке подлежащее всегда находится в начале утвердительного предложения"?
Нет, ну что в нем пространственного. Это грамматика языка... К пространству никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: > Вы имеет в виду высказывания типа "в английском языке подлежащие ввсегда нахоится в начале утвердительного предложения"?

Да, хотя высказывание можно сократить до словосочетания, например: "находиться после сказуемого". Непредикативные синтаксические отношения, насколько мне известно, реализуются уже на уровне словосочетания, как элементарной синтаксической единицы. Но если есть отношения, их можно отнести к какому-то разряду. Интересно, к какому?

Answer (score 0):

> Мне кажется, что в вашем вопросе есть неточность в терминологии, поэтому он так трудно понимается. Существует термин "синтаксическая связь", но нет "синтаксических отношений".

Неточность в терминологии - это может быть. Однако я не думаю, что сочетание "синтаксические отношения" -  терминологическая ошибка.

Не подлежит сомнению факт существования синтаксической связи, которая подразделяется на сочинительную и подчинительную. Основными видами последней являются согласование, управление и примыкание.

Существованию синтаксической связи нисколько не мешает наличествование синтаксических отношений. Их принято делить на предикативные (реализуемые при связи подлежащего и сказуемого) и непредикативные (возникающие между компонентами словосочетания). Непредикативные отношения, в свою очередь, делятся на определительные, или атрибутивные, объектные и обстоятельственные. Насколько мне известно, дальнейшее деление первых двух видов непредикативных синтаксических отношений, подобно делению квантов, невозможно. А вот обстоятельственные отношения с успехом делятся на разряды по значению, аналогичные разрядам обстоятельственных наречий (среди которых разряд тех самых пространственных отношений).

В лингвистической литературе выделяют также субъектные и комплетивные (восполняющие) синтаксические отношения, синтаксические отношения меры и
синтаксические отношения степени.

Этой классификацией, которая, я полагаю, не единственная в своем роде и далеко не самая детализированная, я руководствовалась, задавая этот вопрос.