# "Нарастающий итог" как элемент общей лексики

Tags: грамотная-речь

После вопроса о [пространственных отношениях](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/29518/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0), в котором никто ничего не понял, включая меня, автора вопроса, я решила спросить что-нибудь полегче и выудила из глубин сознания такую злобу дня: в каких случаях выражение "нарастающий итог" как элемент общей лексики, определяющий в предложении предмет или характер совершения действия, употребляется с предлогом "с",  а в каких - без него? Например: "трагизм (с) нарастающим итогом", "препарат действует (с) нарастающим итогом".
Я сформулировала вопрос с помощью примеров, но мне хотелось бы обсудить общие случаи употребления этого сочетания.

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Это какой-то бухгалтерский термин? Я первый раз слышу такое выражение.

Comment: Да, кажется, бухгалтерский, но я предлагаю расширить область его применения.

Comment: Неужели никто больше не желает высказаться?!

Answer (score 1):

Нарастающий итог - экономический  фразеологизм, термин, он не может употребляться так же, как свободное выражение.

Трагизм  не может быть с нарастающим итогом, его никто не подсчитывал.Синоним слова итог в этом значении -сумма, вывод всякого сложенья, количество.  Просто вывод, следствие, плод, последствие, продукт, развязка, исход, эффект - это частичные синонимы, к переносному значению. Нарастающим итогом можно подсчитать прибыль, проценты выплат, а по отношению к трагизму можно сказать "трагизм усиливается с нарастающей силой".
Препарат действует с нарастающим не итогом, а эффектом.

Нарастающий - многозначное слово.

Нарастать -
1.  Вырастать на поверхности чего-л. в каком-либо количестве.

1. Накапливаться в каком-либо количестве (о недоимке, процентах и т.п.).
2. Увеличиваться в размерах.
3. Усиливаться, возрастать

Итог(нарастающий) накапливается, трагизм (нарастающий)усиливается, морская волна(нарастающая) увеличивается в размерах.

Comment: > Трагизм не может быть с нарастающим итогом, его никто не подсчитывал

Если бы язык не допускал появления образных выражений, мы вряд ли смогли бы оценить великолепие литературного искусства.

> Нарастающим итогом можно подсчитать прибыль, проценты выплат... Препарат действует с нарастающим не итогом, а эффектом.

То есть: *подсчитать* *нарастающим* *итогом* (но: *действовать* ***с*** *нарастающим* *эффектом*). Верно?

Comment: Думаю, так.

Answer (score 0):

Трагизм МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ с нарастающим итогом - другое дело, существует ли такой трагизм. Я могу себе представить пьесу, в которой развязка наступает в конце каждого действия, но при этом общая напряженность сюжетной линии от действия к действию не ослабевает, а еще более  усиливается. Но для этого автор должен написать такую пьесу, а театральный критик определить этот прием как художественную находку.

В этом случае "трагизм с нарастающим итогом" будет метафорой, а метафора — это "троп, слово или выражение, употребляемое в переносном значении, в основе которого лежит неназванное сравнение предмета с каким-либо другим на основании их общего признака. Термин принадлежит Аристотелю и связан с его пониманием искусства как подражания жизни".

Однажды кто-то сказал, что дождь «идет»,  и можно представить, как оценили окружающие его метафору. Не исключено, что они долго объясняли, что дождь ходить не может и высказывание это неожиданно, странно и реальности не соответствует.